# Open search results in new tab

Tags: search

I am using [Apache Solr Search](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) on my site, and would like links on the search results page to open in a new window/tab.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  I edited this to reflect the comment below.  No need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You should install Custom Search module as it does provide an option to open results in new tab or lightbox.

https://drupal.org/project/custom_search

Otherwise you can always look into using custom functions or js to achieve the same in your search template.

**Updated Answer**

Since you are using solr and search-result.tpl.php you should have a line like:

```
<a href="<?php print $url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
```

change it by adding target value like:

```
<a href="<?php print $url; ?> target='_blank'><?php print $title; ?></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I am already using a Apache solr search so wanted to know how to edit the search!

Comment: Are you using search-result.tpl.php?

Comment: Yes I am using it.

Comment: Thanks.Is there anyway we could do by using Hook?

Comment: Yes you can do it via hook in either custom module or in template file.

Comment: I finally figured it out go to intranet/modules/search and the look for 
<a href="<?php print $url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
and change that to
<a href="<?php print $url; ?> target='_blank'><?php print $title; ?></a>